# Вывести всё валидное время c помощью регулярных выражений python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

```
import re 
s=r'13:79 24:33 02:60 03:81 23:59 28:64 46:50 14:39 91:19 13:35 02:57 10:10 00:00 59:59 15:51' 
pattern = r'[0-2]{1}[0-3]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}' 
it = re.findall(pattern,s) 
print(*it,sep="\n")
```

Comment: import re
s=r'13:79 24:33 02:60 03:81 23:59 28:64 46:50 14:39 91:19 13:35 02:57 10:10 00:00 59:59 15:51'
pattern = r'[0-2]{1}[0-3]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}'
it = re.findall(pattern,s)
print(*it,sep="\n")

Comment: Это полный код для поиска этого регулярного выражения регулярного

Comment: Весь код добавьте в сам вопрос. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit] под ним.

Comment: Не дает сохранить полный код по нажатию кнопки сохранить. Полный код я разместил в комментариях в следующей строке, после вопроса

Comment: За вас опять поправили ваш вопрос. На будущее почитайте справку: [Справка по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
s = r'13:79 24:33 02:60 03:81 23:59 28:64 46:50 14:39 91:19 13:35 02:57 10:10 00:00 59:59 15:51'
pattern = r'(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]'
it = re.findall(pattern,s)
print(*it,sep="\n")
```

паттерн надо поправить, остальное верно

```
[0-1]\d|2[0-3] 0 или 1 и любая цифра или 2 и от 0 до 3
```